# Algebra involving powers of two when solving for cardinality involving power sets

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, logarithms

What's the proper way of solving this problem (self study)?

Find $m$ if
$|A|=m$, $|B|=m+2$ and $|\mathcal{P}(B)| - |\mathcal{P}(A)| = 48$

Since the numbers are small, I can get $m$=4 pretty much by inspection

I tried the more general approach of making the equation and solving for $m$, but got stuck because my algebra skills are weak:

$2^{(m+2)}-2^m=48$

However, $\mathrm{log}_2(48)$ is hanging me up. Plugging in $m=4$ does satisfy the equation, so I'm just messing up something really obvious here.

Comment: Factorize: $2^{m+2} - 2^m = 48 \Leftrightarrow 2^m3 = 48 \Leftrightarrow 2^m = 16 \Leftrightarrow m = 4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying $\log_2$ at an unnatural position (for, $\log_2$ of a difference doesn't simplify nicely).

It is better to first simplify the left-hand side of the equation:

$$2^{m+2}-2^m = 4\cdot 2^m - 2^m = 3\cdot 2^m$$

Now we get:

$$3\cdot 2^m = 48 \iff 2^m = 16$$

At this point, using $\log_2$ is fruitful.